# Loop and string concatenation not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In javascript

```
           $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=searchbookforassigningbarcode',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {callno:callno},
                    success: function(data){

                        $('.library_info_tbl tbody').empty();
                        if (data.length) {

                            if(data[0]['DataAvail'] != 0)
                            {
                                $("#looplimit").val('');
                                $("#callnostored").val(callno);

                                var arrayofbookissued = [];

                       for(var i in data)
                      {
                                    var book_id = data[i]['book_id'];

                                    var indivudvalbookdetails = data[i]['indivudvalbookdetails'];
                                    var issuehistory = data[i]['issuehistory'];

                                       for(var k in issuehistory)
                                       {
                                           arrayofbookissued.push(issuehistory[k]['acquisitionno']);
                                           console.log(arrayofbookissued);    
                                       }

          for(var j in indivudvalbookdetails) {


          ...
          ...

         '<select id="status' + id + '" class="form-control"'+
                                            for (a = 0; a < arrayofbookissued.length; a++) {
                                             if(arrayofbookissued[a] ==indivudvalbookdetails[j]['acquisitionno'])
                                             {
                                                'disabled'
                                             }
                                            } 
                                            +'>'
                                            +'<option value="Select">Select</option>'+
               ...

                ...
```

The above code is throwing error message at  "for (a = 0; a < arrayofbookissued.length; a++) {" line telling  "unexpected token for"...

Actually I am trying to assign disabled to select element if ndivudvalbookdetails[j]['acquisitionno'] is same as arrayofbookissued[a]

Please help !!!

Comment: A `for` loop is not an expression, so you can’t concatenate it with a string.

Comment: can u please show me how will I achieve this

Comment: You could put your code inside a function that returns a string.

Comment: Build the string in the loop first, then append it. I'd also suggest you take the time to format your code properly. It makes it *much* easier for you, and others, to read

Comment: can u show in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is not an expression, so you can’t concatenate it with a string. – Xufox

```js
var disabled = '';
for (a = 0; a < arrayofbookissued.length; a++) 
{
  if(arrayofbookissued[a] ==indivudvalbookdetails[j]['acquisitionno'])
  {
    disabled = 'disabled';
  }
} 

var myString = '<select id="status' + id + '" class="form-control" '+  disabled +' >';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function isSelectDisabled(arrayofbookissued, acquisitionNo){
    var matchFound = arrayofbookissued.some(function(book){
        return book === acquisitionNo;
    });

    return matchFound ? 'disabled' : '';
}
```

and call it with

```
'<select id="status' + id + '" class="form-control"'+ isSelectDisabled(arrayofbookissued, indivudvalbookdetails[j]['acquisitionno']) +'>'
+'<option value="Select">Select</option>'
```